# A Windows Forms App for Perimeter and Size- Can I improve it further

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to make an app that has 3 radio buttons - each for the options Square, Rectangle and Triangle (corresponding to radioButtonx, where is x is 1,2,3 for the options above). I also have 5 Labels - 3 for the texts"a/b/c=", 1 for the Perimeter and 1 for the Face of the figure. I tried the code just with "if"s but I get an exception,so I have found in my book a variant of code with try and catch:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void radioButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Visible = true; label1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = false; label2.Visible = false;
            textBox3.Visible = false; label3.Visible = false;

        }

        private void radioButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Visible = true; label1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = true; label2.Visible = true;
            textBox3.Visible = false; label3.Visible = false;
        }

        private void radioButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Visible = true; label1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = true; label2.Visible = true;
            textBox3.Visible = true; label3.Visible = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double a, b, c, s, P, p;

            try
            {
                a = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                a = 0; textBox1.Text = "0";
            }
            if (textBox2.Visible)
            {
                try
                {
                    b = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    b = 0; textBox2.Text = "0";
                }
            }
            if (textBox3.Visible)
            {
                try
                {
                    c = double.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                }
                catch (FormatException)
                {
                    c = 0; textBox3.Text = "0";
                }
            }
            if (radioButton1.Checked)
            {
                s = a * a;
                P = 4 * a;
            }
            if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                s = 2 * a + 2 * b;
                P = a * b;
            }
            if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                P = (a + b + c);
                p = (a + b + c)/2;
                s = Math.Sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c));
            }
            label4.Text = "Perimeter=" + P;
            label5.Text = "Face=" + s;

        }
    }
```

where I use a Heron formula for the face of the triangle(doesn't matter).

I am still not completely familiar with how try and catch work but that's not what I am asking about.

I have two questions:
1. Can't I just merge the code for radioButton1.Click and the if code radioButton.Checked into something like this:

```
if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
    try
    {
        a = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        a = 0; textBox1.Text = "0";
    }

    s = a * a;
    P = 4 * a;

}
```

And number 2:

Why is there an error in my code in the last two lines (for Label4 and Label5)?Why does it seem that I can't put them in the end of the if codes in order not to write it inside every single if-block? How do I correct it?

Comment: One thing that will help your coding immensely as you go: any control you interact with, rename.  It shouldn't be `radioButton1`; make it `radioButtonSquare`, etc.  (There are frequently controls you don't interact with - lots of static labels, for example.  If you never do anything to them, it's not bad for them to be named Label1 etc.)  I would even name your TextBox and labels that you set Visible on in some way, just to show that they're ones that matter to you.

Comment: Aside from that, I for one could use a better explanation of your question #1.  Why would you merge the code?  Isn't what happens in each of the click events completely distinct from what should happen in the other events?  And for question #2, I can't reproduce the error.  Please tell us exactly what error you're encountering.

Comment: I know and usually rename my objects but I am currently in a little hurry. As for the second question- since the textBox is available only if the radioButton is checked, then the condition is the same, isn't it? I am new to Programming and I am learning it at school but this is a personal problem which I need not just to solve but to fully understand.:-)

Comment: Please read [ask].  To get the best results, you should split your questions in to two well-written ones.  If it matters to you, you could have one reference the other, but they're on two distinct topics.  You may also want to read up on how to write a [mcve], though that is hard with winforms.  Your best results will come from asking your teacher at school.  The community in Stack Overflow is usually eager to help, but your question #1 is a core understanding question of what a GUI does, and is too big to be explained on here.

Comment: OK. Guess I will have to go on bonus excercises to understand.:-)

Comment: For question number 2:

I do not have a compiler with me and I can not check but I think that you are trying to concatenate a String and a double, thus the error. Convert the numbers by means of `p.ToString()` and `s.ToString()` and you should be fine.

Comment: @Emi987 this was my suspicion, but free online compilers like https://dotnetfiddle.net/CYa3zg don't have any problem with concatenating a double to a string.  (I made that quick test just for that purpose.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

So.. if I understood your code right, you mayn't check `radioButton2.Visible` always, because `radioButton2.Checked` enough for your code. Your code can look like:

```
double a, b, c;  

double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a);
double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out b);
double.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out c);
 if (radioButton1.Checked)
     {...}
 if (radioButton2.Checked)
     {...}
 if (radioButton3.Checked)
     {...}
//{...} => your code
```

This method returns bool. You can use it if you wanna do smth when you couldn't parse. 
Like this:

```
if(!double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a))
{
    a = 0; textBox1.Text = "0";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is related to Quesiton 2 of yours.
Since you did not assign any value to s and p and using to concat string, you are getting error.
To fix this, what you have to do is:
double a, b,c,s,P, p;
a = b = c = s = P = p = 0;